# if statement imacros (Chrome?)

Tags: google-chrome, macros, imacros

I have two questions, the first is, I've done some research and it seems you are not able to create an if statement with imacros, in chrome at least. I think you can run JS with Firefox right?

The question is, can you write an if statement using .iim ?

Question two is, if I can't, would there be any way to make it so instead of a TIMEOUT making the script stop, it would instead just restart/loop the macro? so like:

```
SET !TIMEOUT 60 *so that restart macro on fail*
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/
TAG SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(9)>SPAN>CENTER>DIV>IMG"
```

This would make it so if for some reason it cant click on the google image (what the macro is doing^) it will go back to google.com and repeat the macro

Comment: Should i just use Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you can run JS with Firefox right?

Yes, it's right.


At stackoverflow.com you can find many ideas of how to use logic within 'iim'-macros.

And here is a prompt tip for you:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET sel "HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(9)>SPAN>CENTER>DIV>IMG"

URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG SELECTOR={{sel}} EXTRACT=HTM
SET ifSel EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/img/) ? '{{sel}}' : '';")
TAG SELECTOR={{ifSel}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

SET stop EVAL("if ('{{ifSel}}') MacroError('Already clicked!');")
```

Try to play this macro repeatedly (so called 'loop mode') with the 'Max' value set to a very big arbitrary number (for example, 999999999).

Comment: This is awesome @Shugar it does what i want it too. Could you either tell me or point me in the right direction to understand how it works? it would be much appreciated, thanks again. I'll also try to figure it out on my own

Comment: Well, here is the [right direction](http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference). Hope it helps :)